# How to acquire a complete list of packages and versions for a particular Ubuntu series using launchpadlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, launchpad

I am looking for some help (an example would be excellent) figuring out how to just acquire a list of package names for a certain version of Ubuntu. For example, using the web interface I could simply search in the Ubuntu section of Launchpad for a package, and it will give me all of the sub-packages (components?), e.g.: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta

What I am looking for is a list of upstream packages + all of their sub-packages and all of their dependencies. I'm currently just interested in Ubuntu-17.10-desktop, but I do have an eye toward automation in the future.

Unfortunately the list of provided examples is pretty sparse, so I'm having trouble understanding which function to use.

It took me a while to get here, but this is the code I have so far, which I hope is moving me in the right direction:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
    import launchpadlib as lp

    launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('just testing', 'production', 
    cachedir, version='devel')
    ubuntu = launchpad.distributions['ubuntu']
    series = ubuntu.getSeries(name_or_version='17.10')
    archive = ubuntu.main_archive
    arch_series = series.getDistroArchSeries(archtag='amd64')

    manifest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['asset','pkg_set'])
    pkgs = launchpad.packagesets
    
    for i in range(34):
        name = pkgs.getBySeries(distroseries=series)[i].name
        sources_incl = pkgs.getBySeries(distroseries=series)[i].getSourcesIncluded()
        new_man=pd.DataFrame({'asset':sources_incl,'pkg_set':[name]*len(sources_incl)})
         manifest = manifest.append(new_man,ignore_index=True)
    manifest=manifest.sort_values(by=['asset'])
```

Ideally I should be able to modify this script slightly to change to other Ubuntu series, particularly newer versions. However, I am a novice in the field of API JSON fetching, so I could use some help.

For instance, knowing that there are 34 package sets in Artful I came to through experimentation. It would be nice if there were some property I could fetch to know that answer for a given series.

In addition, I would like to be able to fetch version numbers for each source, specific to Artful, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that except through `.getPublishedSources`, i.e.:

```
    name = 'acpid'
    comp = archive.getPublishedSources(source_name=name,distro_series=series)[0].component_name
    source = archive.getPublishedSources(source_name=name,distro_series=series)[0].source_package_name
    version = archive.getPublishedSources(source_name=name,distro_series=series)[0].source_package_version
```

It does not seem to be allowed to fetch the entirety of the database, instead you must specify a `source_name`.